# Laravel Model Undefined Relationship Issue Only in $with Variable

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, php-7.4

I have encountered a peculiar issue in my Laravel 8.47.0 project that I have not come across before. The problem arises when I include the 'events' relationship in the $with variable of the Order model. The error message states "Undefined relationship [events]".

However, when I fetch the API response, the relationship seems to be loaded seamlessly without any issue. Furthermore, this issue is not replicated on my local machine or the test server.

I tried to ensure that the relationship in the Order model is correctly defined, as seen in the 'events' function. The relationship appears to be functioning correctly when retrieved through the API.

I have attached the relevant code snippets for reference:

Below is the code:

```php
class Order extends BaseModel
{
    use PowerJoins, HasStatuses;
    protected $with = ['user', 'driver', 'statuses', 'taxi_order']; // The issue arises when 'events' is added here.
    // ... (other code)
```

Definition of relationship:

```php
public function events()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\OrderEvent', 'order_id', 'id');
}
```

I have not been able to identify the root cause of this issue, and it has become a puzzling situation for me. This is the first time in my experience with Laravel that I have encountered such a strange problem.

Has anyone faced a similar issue before? Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Can you try it this way `OrderEvent::class` and import it, just as a first go

Comment: Hi. Thanks for this recommendation. Do you mean this?

So the `Order.php` file will look like this:
```php

public function events() {
    return $this->hasMany(OrderEvent::class)->withTrashed();
}
```

Then in `OrderEvent.php`:
```php
 public function order()
 {
     return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Order', 'order_id', 'id');
 }
```

I'll try this one. Thanks.

Comment: do you use softDelete trait ?

Comment: I didn't use the softDelete trait so I removed the `->withTrashed()` in my code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to define the relations here and assuming things

you have a table `order_events` and it has a foreign column called `order_id`, right ?

```php
// Order.php

use App\Models\OrderEvent;

public function events()
{
    return $this->hasMany(OrderEvent::class, 'order_id', 'id');
}
```

```php
// OrderEvent.php

use App\Models\Order;
public function order()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Order::class, 'order_id');
}
```

Is this how it looks like in you side ?

Comment: Yes, but finally it's solved. I also left my findings and how I solved it. :) Thanks btw.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, creating a scope that has `$query->with()` in your eloquent Laravel model can affect your `protected $with = []`. This is a lesson learned for me. You need to make sure that if your code uses a scope of your model, you need to also include the relationship there because `$query->with()` seems to override the eager loading you defined in your `protected $with = []`. In my case, this is what I had to do:

```php
public function scopeFullData($query, $extraWiths = []) {
        $fixedWiths = [
            "products.product", "stops.delivery_address", "user", "driver.vehicle", "delivery_address", "payment_method", "vendor" => function ($query) {
                return $query->withTrashed();
            }, 'package_type', "taxi_order.waypoints", "events" /* added "events" here */
        ];

        $withs = array_merge($fixedWiths, $extraWiths);
        return $query->with($withs);
}
```

Comment: Yes, sure. This is an important lead, which wasn't mentioned before, but good for you that you found it :D